# How do I iterate through xml using Visual Studio generated class?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

firstly let me apologise if this question has been asked before but I have searched hi and low without success.

Within Visual Studio, there is an option to do a 'Paste Special' -> 'Paste XML as Classes' and it has created me the following:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Menus
{

    private MenusTabName[] tabNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TabName")]
    public MenusTabName[] TabName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tabNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tabNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class MenusTabName
{

    private MenusTabNameMenuItem[] menuItemField;

    private string idField;

    private string accessField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MenuItem")]
    public MenusTabNameMenuItem[] MenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.menuItemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.menuItemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string access
    {
        get
        {
            return this.accessField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.accessField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class MenusTabNameMenuItem
{

    private MenusTabNameMenuItemItem[] itemField;

    private MenusTabNameMenuItemMenuItem[] menuItemField;

    private string idField;

    private bool hiddenField;

    private bool hiddenFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Item")]
    public MenusTabNameMenuItemItem[] Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MenuItem")]
    public MenusTabNameMenuItemMenuItem[] MenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.menuItemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.menuItemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool hidden
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hiddenField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hiddenField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool hiddenSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hiddenFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hiddenFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class MenusTabNameMenuItemItem
{

    private byte indexField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte index
    {
        get
        {
            return this.indexField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.indexField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class MenusTabNameMenuItemMenuItem
{

    private MenusTabNameMenuItemMenuItemItem[] itemField;

    private string idField;

    private bool hiddenField;

    private bool hiddenFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Item")]
    public MenusTabNameMenuItemMenuItemItem[] Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool hidden
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hiddenField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hiddenField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool hiddenSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hiddenFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hiddenFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class MenusTabNameMenuItemMenuItemItem
{

    private byte indexField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte index
    {
        get
        {
            return this.indexField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.indexField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The XML is the following:

```
 <Menus>
  <TabName id="TabName1" access="all">
    <MenuItem id="Menu1">
      <MenuItem id="SubMenu1">
        <Item index="0">Item1</Item>
        <Item index="1">Item2</Item>
        <Item index="2">Item3</Item>
        <Item index="3">Item4</Item>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem id="SubItem2" hidden="true">
        <Item index="0">AnotherItem1</Item>
        <Item index="1">AnotherItem2</Item>
        <Item index="2">AnotherItem3</Item>
      </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem id="Menu2">
      <Item index="0">SubItemValue1</Item>
      <Item index="1">SubItemValue2</Item>
      <Item index="2">SubItemValue3</Item>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem id="Menu3" hidden="true">
      <Item index="0">SomeValue1</Item>
      <Item index="1">SomeValue2</Item>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem id="Menu4" hidden="true">
      <Item index="1">Menu4Value1</Item>
      <Item index="2">Menu4Value2</Item>
      <Item index="3">Menu4Value3</Item>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem id="Menu5">
      <Item index="0">Client</Item>
    </MenuItem>
  </TabName>
  <TabName id="TabName2" access="all">
    <MenuItem id="Menu1Text">
      <Item index="0">SomeValue1</Item>
      <Item index="1">SomeValue2</Item>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem id="Menu2Text" hidden="true">
      <Item index="0">SomeMoreValue1</Item>
      <Item index="1">SomeMoreValue2</Item>
      <Item index="2">Addresses</Item>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem id="Menu3Text">
      <Item index="0">Participate1</Item>
      <Item index="1">Participate2</Item>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem id="Menu4Text">
      <Item index="0">Participant1</Item>
    </MenuItem>
  </TabName>
</Menus>
```

In a method, OpenXML(), I have the following code to serialize the XML:

```
public void OpenXML()
{
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Menus));

        _menuStructure = (Menus)serializer.Deserialize(_s);

}
```

Using the _menuStructure, how do I go about iterating through the elements using Lamda expressions or XML to Linq?  I only need the ID's from each tag, except where Item is concerned whereby I just want the values.  How would I store them using container classes - Dictionary, Lists, arrays, a mixture of all of them?

Many thanks.

John

Comment: It is unclear what you have a problem with.

Comment: The same way you would iterate through almost any array? Not sure, what your actual question is. You get an object `_menuStructure` of type `Menus`. That object has the property `TabName` which is an array of objects of type `MenusTabName`. So if you could do something like `foreach (MenusTabName element in _menuStructure.TabName) { // do something with the element }`.

Comment: You can just iterate through the elements. What you get is an object of type Menus, therefore you can access its property...

Comment: Updated explanation to what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where automatic generation of classes from XML doesn't produce very useful results, because the code generator won't understand that you have a recursive hierarchy of related types of classes, and instead will define a different, unrelated class type for each level in the XML file.

Instead, I suggest you define your classes manually.  Here's one version:

```
public abstract class UIItemBase
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<UIItemBase> Items { get; }
}

public abstract class UIItemContainer : UIItemBase
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]  // I put this here because there's no "id" on the "<Item>" entries.  Move to UIItemBase if it makes more sense.
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TabName", typeof(UITab))]
    [XmlElement("MenuItem", typeof(UIMenu))]
    [XmlElement("Item", typeof(UIItem))]
    // Add an [XmlElement("Name", typeof(Class))] for every subclass that might be here.
    public List<UIItemBase> ItemList { get; set; }

    public override IEnumerable<UIItemBase> Items
    {
        get {
            return ItemList;
        }
    }
}

public class UITab : UIItemContainer
{
    [XmlAttribute("access")]
    public string Access { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Menus")]
public class UIMenu : UIItemContainer
{
    [XmlAttribute("hidden")]
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
}

public sealed class UIItem : UIItemBase
{
    [XmlAttribute("index")]
    public int Index { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override IEnumerable<UIItemBase> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<UIItemBase>();
        }
    }
}
```

And then, an extension method for recursively descending a UI item hierarchy:

```
public static class UIItemExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<UIItemBase> WalkItems(this UIItemBase item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            yield break;
        yield return item;
        foreach (var child in item.Items)
            foreach (var subChild in child.WalkItems())
                yield return subChild;
    }
}
```

Having done this, it's easy to use Linq to descend the item hierarchy and pick out desired properties, for instance

```
        var ids = rootMenu.WalkItems().Skip(1).OfType<UIItemContainer>().Select(item => item.Id); // Skip the root menu which has no ID.

        var values = rootMenu.WalkItems().OfType<UIItem>().Select(item => item.Value);
```